# Advice on DB design Best Practices/Standard - Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, standards

I'm designing the DB for a new app which is something I've done a thousand times, but in this occasion I suddenly start wondering on some aspects that I've never stopped before. Is there some standard/recommendation for the following things?

- Whats the recommended data type for storing currencies *(no financial operations, just displaying).*
- Recommended size for storing phone numbers (internationals)
- Recommended minimum size for storing first names / last names *(minimum meaning smallest maximum recommended size)*
- Recommended minimum size for storing comment blocks.*(minimum meaning smallest maximum recommended size also)*

I'm aware that every application has its own particular requirements to consider, but I feel that there must be something more specific than gut feeling and common sense.

Help, as always, will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whats the recommended data type for storing currencies**

This depends on what kind of currency, and to what degree of accuracy.

If it's cents and dollars, rounded to the nearest cent, it's `NUMBER(12,2)` which allows you to store amounts between `-999,999,999,999.99` and `999,999,999,999.99` - which for most currencies should be enough.

If you need to store intermediate results from, say, interest rate calculations, you may need more precision, e.g. `NUMBER(15,5)`.

If you're talking Zimbabwean dollars, perhaps you should choose the maximum `NUMBER` instead :)

**Recommended size for storing phone numbers (internationals)**

VARCHAR2(30) should be sufficient. If it's too long your users will enter all sorts of rubbish data in there.

**Recommended minimum size for storing first names / last names / 
Recommended minimum size for storing comment blocks**

These don't apply since you're in Oracle - use VARCHAR2, so you don't have to worry about minimum size. All you need to specify is the maximum size.

Comment: Ok, I think there is a confusion on what I meant by minimum size... I meant whats the smallest recommended size. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: @Chepech, that's no clearer. "smallest" = "minimum". What are you saying?

Comment: I can make all my name fields VARCHAR2(4000) that way I can store about any real name possible, easy and dirty, but I dont think anyone wants to do that. OMG Ponies recommended a VARCHAR2(30) but I show him a real case we have a guy with a last name of 40+chars (see comments below). So the question is whats the smallest possible VARCHAR2 field that is recommended to use with international names/last names.

Comment: @Chepech, you just answered it yourself: `VARCHAR2(40)`, or **whatever minimum length** you expect to need to store. There is no "standard/recommended/best practice" to adhere to here, apart from "make it as large as necessary, but not too much larger".

Answer (score 1):

### Currencies:

`NUMBER(15,2)`, really depends on how big the numbers are that you expect to run into.

### Phone numbers:

`VARCHAR2(30)`, please don't hurt me if it should be larger - can't remember the length per se just that VARCHAR allows flexibility for formatting.

I don't see the point of looking at the *minimum* size if using VARCHAR2.  The concerns for the physical model revolve around how much space the database will consume over time, assuming fields are maxed out.

### Comment blocks:

Maximum of VARCHAR2(4000)

Comment: The point on asking for the minimum size is because this app is I18N, so we have one case on a previous development where there was a German guy who's last name was Wolfeschaddergelsteinhausenbergerdorffwissenhaf... so I guess you see the problem when having a 30char VARCHAR2 for last names =), But again... this is a weird exception and not a rule.

Comment: @Chepech: Yeah, hyphenated names are fun too.

Comment: Yeah! true story, the guy's name was ironically "Sy" =)

Comment: @Chepech: Clearly, his parents did not like him =)

Answer (score 1):

[EDIFACT](http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d03a/trsd/trsdnad.htm) generally uses 35 as the size of a Name field and I'd copy that (and document that as a basis). Newer stuff tends to be defined in XML and doesn't normally go into field length definitions.

Alternatively the Canadian post office [recommends](http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/tools/advisors/mmadvisor/sl_1w_149x229b.jsf#addressing) no more than 40 characters per address line.

Note, that is characters and not bytes. Sizing should take into account multi-byte characters, but obviously not all names will be the maximum length. I've used ten characters per name as a broad approximation for sizing estimates but that could vary a lot between countries, ethnicities etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know you were asking minimum size for comment blocks, but for large free-text areas you ought to consider using a CLOB value. Oracle is pretty smart about how these things are handled, how the data is stored, etc. You NEVER have to worry about size. In addition, you can usually *pretend* that they are VARCHAR2 columns for easy manipulation.